# Map Drive Username and Password required

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Microsoft server 2008, under that i have different folders to map drive for different users. My question is how could i make the map drive to have a username and password required when logging in for individual users? i already input a username and password in "Connect As (Optional)" tab still can't work. all of the computer are connected in one domain.

Comment: You want the users to be required to enter a username/password when they connect?  Not sure I follow the question...

Comment: Yes sir. Your correct.